# Counting unique ad impressions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, analytics

I am working with a fairly large dataframe that includes three major columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'ad_id': [2441, 102, 133, 102, 102, 2441, 105, 301],
         'user_id': [665, 152, 12, 665, 11, 238, 665, 12],
         'view_time': ['09/12/2017 10:11', '11/12/2017 10:22', '1/12/2017 10:22', '11/12/2017 10:35', '11/12/2017 13:01', '11/12/2017 14:11', '11/12/2017 14:38', '11/12/2017 14:52'],
})
```

where `view_time`seems to be compatible with Pandas `datetime`.

My goal here is to identify and print 4 ads with the highest number of unique views (that is, views by a particular user in 24h window where views recorded after the initial unique view do not count as unique), or, failing that, get *n* ads with the highest number of nonduplicate (different `view_time` values for any given user) views.

I have tried to use the following:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['ad_id'], as_index=False).agg({'user_id': pd.Series.nunique, 'view_time': pd.Series.nunique})
```

but this seems to provide little help either in counting properly unique views or in sorting `ad_id` values on the basis of viewcount, however gross it might be.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please, with a reproducible data sample and expected output that makes it clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = df.assign(
    view_time=
    pd.to_datetime(df.view_time).dt.date
).drop_duplicates()

d.groupby('ad_id').size().nlargest(4)
```